# PrimeFaces fileupload

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, primefaces, jspx

I am using jsp/Servlet into a project and I have decided to migrate to JSF using PrimeFaces ,I have faced a problem while trying to upload file using PrimeFaces fileupload control then when I have configured it into web.xml it worked well , the problem now that all old jsp file upload way is not working:

```
 DiskFileUpload upload = new DiskFileUpload();
 List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, a HTTP request can be parsed only once. The client ain't going to send it for a second time if you need to parse it twice. Your problem indicates that the PrimeFaces file upload filter is for some reason also invoked on a plain JSP/Servlet request and thus parses the upload for JSF before plain JSP/Servlet get chance to parse it for own use. This should not happen.

You need to map the PrimeFaces file upload filter on JSF requests only, not on plain JSP/Servlet requests. You normally achieve that by mapping it to the `FacesServlet`.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

*(the `<servlet-name>` must be exactly the same value as is been used in `<servlet>` definition of the `FacesServlet` class; the `<filter-name>` is obviously exactly the same value as is been used in `<filter>` definiton of the file upload filter class)*

Or, if that old JSP/Servlet file upload approach is been used straight in a JSF page for some unobvious reason, then you need to map the PrimeFaces file upload filter on a more specific URL pattern covering only the pages containing the PrimeFaces file upload component.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/upload.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

*(if you've mapped the `FacesServlet` on for example `*.jsf` instead of `*.xhtml`, then you should obviously change the URL pattern to `/upload.jsf`)*

Note that you can specify multiple `<url-pattern>` entries on a single filter mapping, which is useful for the case that you've multiple pages containing the PrimeFaces file upload component.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/upload1.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/upload2.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/upload3.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```